# Git Svn clone certain revision, and continue cloning other revisions in the future

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am converting my svn repo to git. It is a very large repo and it keep failing, therefore I have to clone only part of it. I used the following command:

```
git svn clone -r100000:HEAD https://svn.myserver.com/project/ .
```

It completed succesfully, but I only have the latest few commits. Is there anyway to continue cloning the earlier commits?

P.S: cloning the entire repo without -r always result in RA layer request failed: REPORT request failed on 'svn/project/!svn/vcc/default': ... could not read chunk size: Secure connection truncated ... Sometimes, it is after a few days... so I decided to abandon it and clone only partially

EDIT: Add the error message

RA layer request failed: REPORT request failed on '/svn/project/!svn/vcc/default': REPORT of '/svn/project/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read chunk size: Secure connection truncated (https://svn.myserver.com) at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN/Ra.pm line 282

Answer (score 6):

If you want the entire history, why not start at your svn repo's rev 1? Granted it will take a while, but you could do it in parts. For example:

```
git svn clone -r1:10000 https://svn.myserver.com/project/ .
```

Once that completes cd into **project** and run:

```
git svn fetch svn -r10000:20000
```

you can even overlap:

```
git svn fetch svn -r9997:20000
```

and it'll skip past the pieces it already got. You may just not want to create gaps.

And I recognize that you've tried to pull it all before without any -r spec and got errors, but maybe doing it in sections will get past that. If you do get an error, try running the same command again. In using `git svn clone` in the past I've had many cases of it losing connection or having random errors, but cd-ing into the project and `git svn fetch` or `rebase`-ing (sometimes repeatedly) seems to keep picking up where it left off before.

Comment: sadly, it failed again with the same error message: Index mismatch: 907786790b14a445c2b5eef420311bea543b597c != 09b95548bc4f106b1bb5
7be669737878067e1f4c
rereading ac49f8e7dbfaeaa3cf500b946c6ebe50abb735ee
        M       App/asset/gui/ReadMe.txt
RA layer request failed: REPORT request failed on '/svn/sg/!svn/vcc/default': R
EPORT of '/svn/sg/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read chunk size: Secure connecti
on truncated (https://192.168.1.107) at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN/Ra.pm
line 282

Answer (score 1):

with git you cannot add history "in front of" what you already have. every git commit references ALL COMMITS EVER that it is a successor to (via inclusion of a hash of these commits). it is possible to rewrite history (and add new commits in front), but that gives you totally new commits (changed hashes) and is not what you want to do in an actively used repo.

you should either grab as much history as you can and claim it an "initial import", or try to fix the import problem. when you talk about days, it sounds as if you could benefit from moving closer to the svn repo, i.e. run the commands on the svn server itself to spare network overhead/latency.

also it might help to give more information about the actual errors you encounter.

Comment: So, does that mean that if I clone from R.100000 onwards, the earliest history that I will ever had in my Git repo is R.100000? there is no way to fetch the earlier history (commits) later after the initial clone?

Comment: at least it will be difficult to integrate the up-to-100k branch with the starting-at-100k branch. if you create them independently you need to rewrite the starting-at-100k branch when you tack it onto the up-to-100k branch, which will cause all the usual problems with rewritten history, or you could use grafts (n.b. i never used them): https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint --- by far the best solution is to import the whole thing in one piece if possible.